# How to get notifications from Openfire when users connect?

Tags: xmpp, openfire

Being new to XMPP and OpenFire i am looking for a way to get notifications when users connect and disconnect from a server. I would like to push these notifications to others systems, for logging purposes for example. Is there an easy way on how an external program could get notified when users connect/disconnect?

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest approach would be to create a plugin to monitor connection activity and log it to the external system.